# how many string can display on full screen

Tags: java, android

I've large string, i want to split it. i got screen width and height using below code,

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

screenHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
screenWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
```

I want to know how many character to display on screen.

how to calculate ? and split the string.?

Answer (score 1):

On a Swing / AWT Java platform, you could use a [`FontMetrics`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html) object to measure the width of the particular characters you are trying to display.

References:

- [How to calculate the font's width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524855/how-to-calculate-the-fonts-width)

But it would probably be simpler to use something that can take care of the character rendering and wrapping for you.

On the Android platform, the [Paint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html) class has a number of methods that will help you do this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

use the substring method

`String substring(int startIndex, int endIndex)`

split the strings per line and store them in an array of Strings

```
String originalString=" ....some long text " ;
String stringsByLine[]= new String(screenHeight);
int i,j=0;
for ( i = 0; j<originalString.length;i++,j++){
  stringsByLine[i]=originalString.substring(j,j+screenWidth);
  j+=screenWidth;
}
```

havent tried it myself, but this logic should work. :-)

Answer (score 0):

i think if you set width property to wrapcontent than string automatically split and display on next line.

use this property

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```