# Swing drawString: Text bounds and line wrapping

Tags: java, swing, layout, graphics

I need to draw text with [Graphics#drawString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawString(java.lang.String,%20int,%20int))

I'm drawing on top of a `JPanel` that changes both in width and height (by dragging).

I'm looking for a solution to generate bounds, so that I can warp the lines automatically and adapt the text accordingly, without overflows.

I figured I could just hardcode it myself by getting the length in pixels with fontMetrics, however, I would rather have a component that does this automatically (`drawString` also doesn't support `'\n'`).

In the docs as well as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524855/how-to-calculate-the-fonts-width) other answer I found this:

```
Graphics2D g = ...;
Point2D loc = ...;
Font font = Font.getFont("Helvetica-bold-italic");
FontRenderContext frc = g.getFontRenderContext();
TextLayout layout = new TextLayout("This is a string", font, frc);
layout.draw(g, (float)loc.getX(), (float)loc.getY());

Rectangle2D bounds = layout.getBounds();
bounds.setRect(bounds.getX()+loc.getX(),
              bounds.getY()+loc.getY(),
              bounds.getWidth(),
              bounds.getHeight());
g.draw(bounds);
```

Which does draw the string and the bounds, but they have no effect, so no luck here.

**Any class I could use?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Any class I could use?

Another option is to use a [LineBreakMeasurer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/font/LineBreakMeasurer.html):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.font.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.Objects;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public final class LineBreakMeasurerTest {
  private static final String TEXT = "1234567890 ABCDEFG HIJKLMN OPQRSTU VWXYZ";
  private final JLabel    lbl1 = new JLabel(TEXT);
  private final JTextArea lbl2 = new JTextArea(TEXT);
  private final JLabel    lbl3 = new WrappingLabel(TEXT);
  public JComponent makeUI() {
    Border b = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GREEN,  5);
    lbl1.setBorder(
        BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(b, "JLabel"));
    lbl2.setBorder(
        BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(b, "JTextArea"));
    lbl3.setBorder(
        BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(b, "LineBreakMeasurer"));

    lbl2.setFont(lbl1.getFont());
    lbl2.setEditable(false);
    lbl2.setLineWrap(true);
    lbl2.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    lbl2.setBackground(lbl1.getBackground());

    JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 1));
    p.add(lbl1);
    p.add(lbl2);
    p.add(lbl3);
    return p;
  }

  public static void main(String... args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
      UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);
      JFrame f = new JFrame();
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      f.getContentPane().add(new LineBreakMeasurerTest().makeUI());
      f.setSize(320, 240);
      f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      f.setVisible(true);
    });
  }
}

class WrappingLabel extends JLabel {
  //TEST: private AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(.8, 1d);
  protected WrappingLabel(String text) {
    super(text);
  }
  @Override protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2.setPaint(getForeground());
    Insets i = getInsets();
    float x = i.left;
    float y = i.top;
    int w = getWidth() - i.left - i.right;

    AttributedString as = new AttributedString(getText());
    //TEST: as.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FONT, g2.getFont());
    //TEST: as.addAttribute(TextAttribute.TRANSFORM, at);
    AttributedCharacterIterator aci = as.getIterator();
    FontRenderContext frc = g2.getFontRenderContext();
    LineBreakMeasurer lbm = new LineBreakMeasurer(aci, frc);

    while (lbm.getPosition() < aci.getEndIndex()) {
      TextLayout tl = lbm.nextLayout(w);
      tl.draw(g2, x, y + tl.getAscent());
      y += tl.getDescent() + tl.getLeading() + tl.getAscent();
    }
    g2.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: If you want the text centered, you can use this instead of `x`, `float xPos = (float) (x + ((getWidth() - tl.getBounds().getWidth()) / 2))`

Answer (score 2):

Simplest solution: use a JTextArea.

You can rig it up so that it doesn't even look like a JTextArea by setting background to null, by making it nonfocusable, and it will automatically wrap words if you call `setLineWrap(true)` and `setWrapStyleWord(true)` on it. To have it fill the JPanel, give the panel a BorderLayout, and add the JTextArea BorderLayout.CENTER. You can even set a margin if desired.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tought of that, but is there no other way?
 I'd have a lot of trouble doing that, as it's not one united text. It's a lot of small strings, not alligned, with different format, color, specs. 
Here's a much simplified schema with a few: http://imgur.com/4zKTppM
The red table is imaginary and drawn only to show the alignments.
The strings update independently, this panel is VERY small and there are a quite a lot of them..