# Is it possible to get the right string size without use paintComponent(Graphics g)?

Tags: java, swing

Actually I have these methods to get the width/height size of a string, both requires the command inside a paint component. But **I want to get this values inside a class constructor**. This is possible?

```
public int getStringWidth(Graphics g){
    g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    metrics = g2d.getFontMetrics(this.font);
    return metrics.stringWidth(this.string);
}

public int getStringHeight(Graphics g){
    g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    metrics = g2d.getFontMetrics(this.font);
    int height = (int)font.createGlyphVector(metrics.getFontRenderContext(), this.string).getVisualBounds().getHeight();    
    return height;
}
```

`font.createGlyphVector(metrics.getFontRenderContext(), this.string).getVisualBounds().getHeight()` it's the best command that I got to precisely calculate the string height size and it needs `Graphics g` too.

Comment: I'm using FontMetrics in this code and needs `Graphics g` to work

Comment: I deleted my previous comment which was not clear. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524855/how-to-calculate-the-fonts-width

Comment: Yes you can get FontMetrics objects from other objects than Graphics:  swing components for example. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/class-use/FontMetrics.html

Comment: *"But **I want to get this values inside a class constructor**."* Why? See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: @AndrewThompson, the problem is that I have to wait 1 repaint to get the Sprites values, and paintComponent is to draw graphics on the panel and not to initialize graphics, I simplily want to initialize the graphics on the class constructor

Comment: Sprites? What sprites? For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson I think that is not needed my code about Sprite to this question, in question about getting properties values of a graphic, Strings is the only one who needs the paintComponent to get width and height and this is the problem, if I initialize a square in class constructor its simples to get the width and height inside the class constructor because I define the numbers, the properties of the strings is generated by the string itself and Java forces me to use the paintComponent to get the properties, got it?

Comment: *"I think that is not needed.."* Do you need an ***answer?*** Do you need the close attention of people who ***can*** answer this? Your answers so far do not give me the answer to my question, at least, not enough to motivate me to look closely at the problem. So .. good luck with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a BufferedImage with the right size and use createGraphics() on it to get an actual Graphics object that is drawable.

```
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics g = img.createGraphics();
```