# Java Font :how many pixels are being used for the width of a particular character

Tags: java

I need to find out how many pixels are being used for the width of a particular character in java- for example, the width of the characters '3' and '1' in pixels.

Any Ideas?

Comment: I think you need to provide us with a little more context. Under what API are you trying to achieve this and to what purpose

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate the display width of a string in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258486/calculate-the-display-width-of-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 4):

Within graphics you have FontMetrics which can give you the answer using the method [`stringWidth`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html#stringWidth%28java.lang.String%29), like so:

```
FontMetrics metrics = g.getFontMetrics(font);
int width = metrics.stringWidth("3");
```