# How do you center text in a object and allow it to move around with the object

Tags: java, awt

So I have an oval and I want to be able to put my name in it so that when I move the oval the name stays in the middle.

Also when I `repaint()`, how do I clear what's there first, so there aren't multiple objects?

Here is my current code:

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
{

    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    g.drawOval(spot, spot, 200, 200);

    int spotName = spot +60;
    int spotName_2 = spot_2 + 100;
    String text = "Name";
    g.drawString(text, spotName, spotName_2);


    //add image
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);

 }
```

Comment: One way, draw both on a buffered image and then draw the image in the painting method. Also, read the Swing painting tutorial to see what you are doing wrong (e.g. no super method call and overriding the wrong method)

Comment: Im sorry but i dont understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should get the text centred within the circle:

```
int spotNameX = spot+100-((g.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(text)/2));
int spotNameY = spot+100;

g.drawString(text, spotNameX, spotNameY);
```

`spot` is the left-most side of the circle (its left-most `x` position). If we add `100` to it (half of `200`, i.e. half the width of the circle), we get the `x` position in the exact centre of the circle. However, if we were to draw the text here, then it would be too far over - to be centred, half of the text needs to be on the left side, and half needs to be on the right side.

Thus, to properly centre, you need to [get the width of the text in pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258486/calculate-the-display-width-of-a-string-in-java), and then divide it in half and subtract that from the previously calculated value.

To put it another way:

> (leftmost side + half of width) - (half of width of object to centre) = starting x coord of object to centre

---

With regards to your other question, it should automatically clear when the `paint(Graphics g)` function is called by Swing. If it doesn't, try adding

```
super.paint(g);
```

as the first line inside your `paint(Graphics g)` function, and that may get it working.