# What is the supported method of calculating string width (pixels) in JDK 10

Tags: java, javafx, fontmetrics

I don't want to use AWT.
I was using FontMetrics.computeStringWidth() but is gone in JDK 10 breaking my app. Is there an alternative that doesn't require bringing a new framework (I'm using javafx)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate the display width of a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258486/calculate-the-display-width-of-a-string-in-java)

Comment: see [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html#stringWidth(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Text` and get the size from the `boundsInLocal` property. (The `Text` node does not need to be attached to a scene for this to work.)

The following code keeps the width of the `Rectangle` the same as the size of the `Text`.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Text text = new Text();
    TextField textField = new TextField();
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 20);

    textField.textProperty().addListener((o, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        text.setText(newValue);
        rect.setWidth(text.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth());
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(textField, text, rect), 600, 400);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: "The `Text` node does not need to be attached to a scene for this to work." => does this mean the layout is performed immediately upon initialization (and subsequent changes)? Can it be performed outside of the JavaFX UI thread?